# how to implement mutation responses on a local falcor Model dataset

Tags: falcor

Given that I have an example Model:

```
var model = new falcor.Model({
  cache: {
    userById: {
      "1": {
        name: "User",
        email: "user@email.com"
      }
    },

    users: {
      current: null
    }
  }
});
```

This is a local model that I'm using for testing purposes, and I would like to implement it on a call to `users.login` so the user so that I can call:

```
model.call(['users', 'login'], ['user', 'password'])
```

I realized that if I do this:

```
var model = new falcor.Model({
  cache: {
    userById: {
      "1": {
        name: "User",
        email: "user@email.com"
      }
    },

    users: {
      current: null,
      login: function(user, password) {
        console.log('this code is reached', user, password);

        // what to return in order to mutate model?
      }
    },
  }
});
```

When I do the call it gets there, but I can't figure out how to mutate the model as part of the response; on the server side we return the paths with values and invalidates, and it just works, but here I tried:

```
// trying returning as a jsonGraph response, don't work
login: function() {
  return {
    jsonGraph: {
      users: {
        current: {$type: "ref", value: ['userById', '1']}
      }
    },
    paths: [['users', 'current']]
  }
}

// trying returning as a path set mutation list, don't work
login: function() {
  return [{path: ['users', 'current'], value: {$type: "ref", value: ['userById', '1']}}]
}

// trying force call to set on the model, don't work
login: function() {
  this.set([
    {path: ['users', 'current'], value: {$type: "ref", value: ['userById', '1']}}
  ])
}

// trying using ModelResponse, got an example on some external sources, don't work
login: funtion() {
  return new ModelResponse((observer) => {
    observer.onNext({
      jsonGraph: {
        users: {
          current: {$type: "ref", value: ['userById', '1']}
        }
      },
      paths: [['users', 'current']]
    });

    observer.onCompleted();
  });
}
```

Now I don't know what else to try; I need a simple way to declare mutations after a call into a local model, if you know how to solve this, please let me know here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The client model cache only supports [JSONGraph](https://netflix.github.io/falcor/doc/global.html#JSONGraph), which b/c it is essentially just JSON with some conventions, doesn't support functions.  So, when working with a falcor model cache and no dataSource/middle tier router, it is not possible to implement calls.

This can be kind of annoying when prototyping/testing, as a router is conceptually more difficult than a simple JSON cache object.  I ran into this a while ago, so I wrote a dataSource module to support it: [falcor-local-datasource](https://www.npmjs.com/package/falcor-local-datasource).  The dataSource is initialized with a graph object that *does* support function nodes, and as with your above examples, will mutate the graph based on the function's returned [JSONGraphEnvelope](https://netflix.github.io/falcor/doc/global.html#JSONGraphEnvelope) or an array of [PathValues](https://netflix.github.io/falcor/doc/global.html#PathValue).